# How do I remove ChainMap method to save as JSON file?

Tags: python, json

I'm using ChainMap method for dictionary data and I tried to save(dumps) as a JSON file but it didn't work, and the message is that

> "TypeError: Object of type 'ChainMap' is not JSON serializable"

Example:

```
t = [ChainMap({'a': 'ITT002', 'b': {'c': '2', 'd': '2', 'e': '2'}, 'f': '2'}, {'g': {'h1': {'i': '22', 'j': '2', 'k': '2', 'l': '2', 'n': '2'}}})]
```

if I have a data `t`, is there any ways to save in a JSON file?

Have a nice day Stack brothers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `Chainmap` groups multiple dicts and returns a `view`.To dump it, you have to convert it to dict.

**Here is a minimal example:**

```
import collections
import json

a = {'a': 'A', 'c': 'C'}
b = {'b': 'B', 'c': 'D'}

m = collections.ChainMap(a, b)
print(json.dumps(dict(m)))
>>{"b": "B", "a": "A", "c": "C"}
```

**This is your specific example:** You have to access the `index` of your `list` to access the `ChainMap` object:

```
t = [collections.ChainMap({'a': 'ITT002', 'b': {'c': '2', 'd': '2', 'e': '2'}, 'f': '2'}, {'g': {'h1': {'i': '22', 'j': '2', 'k': '2', 'l': '2', 'n': '2'}}})]
print(json.dumps(dict(t[0])))
>>{"f": "2", "g": {"h1": {"i": "22", "j": "2", "k": "2", "l": "2", "n": "2"}}, "b": {"c": "2", "d": "2", "e": "2"}, "a": "ITT002"}
```

Comment: If this was helpful for you please upvote or accept the answer :)